# Problem obtaining residual data in a nuclei segmentation program

Tags: python, k-means, image-segmentation

I'm trying to get a mask over image cores like this so I can count them later.
[image]

For this, I am performing different steps in Colab:

- Color processing
- Segmentation using K-means
- Find contours to detect those cells

Here is the code:

```
import sys 
import os
import cv2
import copy
import numpy as np

#Load images (600x600x3)
img = cv2.imread("corte3031malo.tif")
if img is None:
    print('The file doesn\'t contain an image')
    sys.exit(1)

WIDTH = img.shape[1]
HEIGHT = img.shape[0]

#Preprocessing
lab_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit =2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
cl_img_l = clahe.apply(lab_img[:,:,0])

#Segmentation
# Define criteria = ( type, max_iter = 10 , epsilon = 1.0 )
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
# Set flags (Just to avoid line break in the code)
flags = cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS

data = np.float32(cl_img_l.flatten().reshape(cl_img_l.shape[0]*cl_img_l.shape[1]))   # reshaping the image to accomodate it as a data matrix

K = 3 #Nuclei, background and others
compactness,labels,centers = cv2.kmeans(data,K,None,criteria,10,flags)
centers = np.uint8(centers)
clustered_image = centers[labels.flatten()]
clustered_image = clustered_image.reshape(img[:,:,0].shape)
print('centers: ')
for k in range(0,K):                                             # Show in console the BGR values of these centers
    print(centers[k]) 
cv2.imshow("clustered image",clustered_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

print('Compactness = ', compactness)        # Show in console the measurement of how compact are the clusters around their centroids
print('Compactness*K = ', compactness*K)    # Using a simple measurement to find when to stop increasing clusters (Colors)

#Contours
_, nuclei = cv2.threshold(clustered_image, np.max(centers)-1, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(nuclei, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

img_contours = np.zeros((HEIGHT,WIDTH), np.uint8)  
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if 50 < area < 500 | True:
        cv2.drawContours(img_contours, contours, i, (255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
cv2.imshow("contours",img_contours)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#Mask
_, mask = cv2.threshold(img_contours, np.max(centers)-1, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

cv2.imshow("Masked", masked)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

My problem is that I am having a lot of background "noise", since you can still see the stroma and part of the cytoplasm. Here's a photo of what I get.

[image]

Do you have any ideas to get better results?

Answer (score 0):

Shape of nuclie is circular while shape of other features is irregular. Thus other features will have more variation in second direction. PCA or eigen values can be used to measure priciple directions of variations. If the magnitude of variation is more in one direction, then it is not nuclei.

```
import numpy.linalg as lg


relevant = []
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
   area = cv2.contourArea(c)
   if 50 < area < 500 | True:
      relevant.append(c)

eigen_values =[]
```

##### eigen values for relevant contours with areas between 50 and 500

```
for c in relevant:
    cov = np.cov(np.reshape(c,(c.shape[0],c.shape[2])).T)
    va, v = lg.eig(cov)
    eigen_values.append(va)
```

##### select contours where eigen values are different by more than 10 pixels

```
img_contours = np.zeros((HEIGHT,WIDTH), np.uint8) 
counter =0
for i, val in enumerate(eigen_values):
    if abs(val[0]-val[1])<10:
        counter = counter+1
        cv2.drawContours(img_contours, relevant, i, (255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
  
print(f"Total nuclie {counter}")
```

I get around 112 nuclei [image: Contours of relevant shape]